# PyGtk3 What is and what does the do_clicked method of Gtk.Button do?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk3

I want to learn how Gtk.Button.do_clicked method works. please give me an example for learning this. thanks.

Comment: I suppose it's private method. I would bet it's default handler for `clicked` signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a virtual method: http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Button.html#virtual-methods

That means you can override it in a subclass of `Gtk.Button` and change the behaviour of the class. You are not meant to call the method directly.